# Java 9 - How to see help on Jshell?

Tags: java, java-9

Anybody here familiar with any good documentation on how could we work with jshell. I am struggling even to find help for same inside the jshell. Any good reference will work too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In console when you run jshell just type `/help`

Also you may see verbose description and options for single command by type help before command in console, example: `jshell> /help /list`

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/commands.htm#JSHEL-GUID-F4881B8E-8B6C-4906-A100-E78C4AFC277D):

> **Tab Completion for Commands**
>
> Similar to snippet completion, when you enter commands and command
>   options, use the Tab key to automatically complete the command or
>   option. If the completion can’t be determined from what was entered,
>   then possible choices are provided.
>
> The following example shows the feedback when Tab is pressed after the
>   leading slash (/) for commands:
>
> ```
> jshell> /<Tab>
> /!          /?          /drop       /edit       /env        /exit       /help
> /history    /imports    /list       /methods    /open       /reload     /reset      
> /save       /set        /types      /vars     
>
> <press tab again to see synopsis>
>
> jshell> /
> ```

Comment: Funny thing is, this is literally printed when you start jshell: *"For an introduction type: /help intro"*

Comment: you are right buddy! My bad It's clearly  printed there. But as an obligation to Stackoverflow I have to accept the answer :). Also please put same as answer too .

Comment: @fxrbfg please don't include images of text, it is bad for search engines to index and bad for accessibility. I've fixed it for you this time :)

Comment: another point in linux when pressed CTRL + C it actually goes to next Jshell line.

Comment: use `/help intro` to get started.

Answer (score 2):

Well though you got a answer, I think anybody will get almost all information from [oracle docs for REPL i.e. JSHELL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm#JSHEL-GUID-465BA4F5-E77D-456F-BCB7-D826AC1E18AE)

This is a really nice documentation.

Also, we have another good documentation [here](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222)

Comment: Thanks! First link is explaining everything needed.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer docs in PDF than reading in CMD. It is same as it is on the online documentation from Oracle.

**[Java Shell User’s Guide - Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/JSHEL.pdf)**